# Переход при выборе двух элементов

Tags: javascript

Есть два списка в каждом по 3 элемента: пусть будут 1-1, 1-2, 1-3 и 2-1, 2-2, 2-3.
Нужен алгоритм при котором при клике например 1-1 и 2-1 перекидывало на одну страницу, а например при клике на 1-3 и 2-1 на совсем другую
Кучу статей прочитал и никак не могу сообразить...

```css
.ben1{
  background-color: green;
}
.ben2{
  background-color: red;
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover{
  background-color: cadetblue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="ben1">
  <ul>
      <li>1-1</li>
      <li>1-2</li>
      <li>1-3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="ben2">
  <ul>
      <li>2-1</li>
      <li>2-2</li>
      <li>2-3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посидел, потупил и вот что придумал. Код работает, но очень грязный... Просьба исправить меня если это так:

```js
var selected = 0;

$('#1-1').on('click', function() {
  selected = 1;
});

$('#1-2').on('click', function() {
  selected = 2;
});

$('#1-3').on('click', function() {
  selected = 3;
});

$('#2-1').on('click', function() {
  if (selected == 1) {
    window.location.href = "http://1-1to2-1";
    selected = 0;
  }
  if (selected == 2) {
    window.location.href = "http://1-2to2-1";
    selected = 0;
  }
  if (selected == 3) {
    window.location.href = "http://1-3to2-1";
    selected = 0;
  }
  selected = 4;
});

$('#2-2').on('click', function() {
  if (selected == 1) {
    window.location.href = "http://1-1to2-2";
    selected = 0;
  }
  if (selected == 2) {
    window.location.href = "http://1-2to2-2";
    selected = 0;
  }
  if (selected == 3) {
    window.location.href = "http://1-3to2-2";
    selected = 0;
  }
  selected = 5;
});

$('#2-3').on('click', function() {
  if (selected == 1) {
    window.location.href = "http://1-1to2-3";
    selected = 0;
  }
  if (selected == 2) {
    window.location.href = "http://1-2to2-3";
    selected = 0;
  }
  if (selected == 3) {
    window.location.href = "http://1-3to2-3";
    selected = 0;
  }
  selected = 6;
});
```

```css
.ben1{
  background-color: green;
}
.ben2{
  background-color: red;
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover{
  background-color: cadetblue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ben1">
  <ul>
      <li><div id="1-1">1-1</div></li>
      <li><div id="1-2">1-2</div></li>
      <li><div id="1-3">1-3</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="ben2">
  <ul>
      <li><div id="2-1">2-1</div></li>
      <li><div id="2-2">2-2</div></li>
      <li><div id="2-3">2-3</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```